# How to convert a string date without zero padding and separator to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

It's a stupid question. but I have date in a string without zero padding and any separator like following:

```
string date = "2016111";
```

Is there a way to convert it to date format using C# lib or any other way? I am not sure about last three digits, either last one digit - it can be day or the last two digits can be day.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you run into the problem such as the date you provided in that it's not clear what the date is supposed to mean. Is that January 11th, or is it November 1st?

Comment: `"2016111"` - is it `2016 Nov 1` or `2016 Jan 11`?

Comment: That is a terrible, terrible format. Rather than try to parse it, I suggest you fix whatever's producing it. If you've already fixed that and want to parse data that you can't regenerate, please state in the question how you want to handle ambiguities.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(...)`

Comment: @JonSkeet - I would assume that the OP has mis-typed the date and he should have put either `"20160111"` or `"20161101"`. Otherwise it's not just a bad format, instead it is completely unusable.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I wouldn't assume that, given that the title includes "without zero padding".

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes, fair enough. Ambiguous land, here we come.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general case, you *can't*: your own example demonstrates this. Does `"2016111"` mean

```
2016 Nov 1    // 2016-11-1
```

or

```
2016 Jan 11   // 2016-1-11
```

Technically, you can put

```
  string date = "2016111";

  var result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, 
    "yyyyMd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

And obtain

```
   1 Nov 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, you can't, sometimes you obtain two valid dates.
But maybe this approach can be useful for you.

```
public static List<DateTime> ParseAmbiguousDate(string str)
{
    var result = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime d;

    if (str.Length == 8)
    {  
        //note that you have to change the format depending on your culture info
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out d))
        {
            result.Add(d);
            return result;
        }
    }
    else if (str.Length == 7)
    {
        var str1 = str.Insert(4, "0");
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str1, "yyyyMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out d))
        {
            result.Add(d);
        }

        var str2 = str.Insert(6, "0");
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str2, "yyyyMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out d))
        {
            result.Add(d);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```